# How do I create/manage GCP API keys using Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to access Google Cloud API Services using client libraries like Python, however there is nothing I can find from the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en). The documentation really confusing to find. Any help please.

What i need is to create API Keys using client library for the customers who can access the API gateway using API keys.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for now to create API keys programmatically. I saw a beta version month ago, but now it's no longer available.

I recently view a video with a new API from Googler, but not publicly documented.

So, you can use this API call (not document, subject to change without notice. Use on your own risk)

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -X POST https://apikeys.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/apiKeys
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method#about_api_key_authentication_for), If you are using an API key for authentication, you must first enable API key support for your service, then to identify a service that sends requests to your API, you use a service account.

Having said that, you can [create a service account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) using the Cloud Console, the gcloud tool, the `serviceAccounts.keys.create()` method, the following example is included in the documentation to create the service account key with Python.

```
import os

from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

def create_key(service_account_email):
    """Creates a key for a service account."""

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    key = service.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().create(
        name='projects/-/serviceAccounts/' + service_account_email, body={}
        ).execute()

    print('Created key: ' + key['name'])
```

You can find another example in this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iam/api-client/service_account_keys.py)

Comment: Worked well thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google's API, better to create service account and use it in Python code.
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production?hl=en

If you have already created service and you want to expose APIs using API Key then you can follow the instruction in the link you mentioned.

Comment: i want to create API Keys using client library

Comment: There is no option to create API key programmatically. You need to use Cloud console.